# How to Comma separate multiple rows obtained from a SQL Query

Tags: sql, asp.net, csv

I wrote a query as :

```
select tbl1.Id, tbl1.FirstName, tbl1.MiddleInit, tbl1.LastName, tbl1.SocialSecNum, tbl1.DateOfBirth, 
tbl1.EyeColor, tbl1.Sex, tbl1.AlertNotes, tbl1.RiskNotes, tbl1.Height, tbl1.[Weight], tbl1.AllergyNotes, 
tbl2.HairColor, tbl3.SexualConsent, tbl4.MaritalStatus, tbl5.Ethnicity, tbl6.Veteran, tbl7.Religion, tbl8.Race, 
tbl9.[Language] as [Language]

from

(SELECT C.Id, C.FirstName, C.MiddleInit, C.LastName, C.SocialSecNum, C.DateOfBirth, C.Sex, 
GL.LookupItem as EyeColor, CC.AlertNotes, CC.RiskNotes, CC.Height, CC.[Weight], CC.AllergyNotes  
FROM dbo.Client C INNER JOIN dbo.ClientCharacteristic CC ON C.Id = CC.ClientId INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=CC.glEyeColorId) tbl1,  

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as HairColor  
FROM dbo.ClientCharacteristic CC INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=CC.glHairColorId) tbl2,

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as SexualConsent  
FROM dbo.ClientCharacteristic CC INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=CC.glSexConsentId) tbl3,

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as MaritalStatus  
FROM dbo.Client C INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=C.glMaritalStatusId where C.Id=2) tbl4,

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as Ethnicity 
FROM dbo.GeneralLookupTransition GLT INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=GLT.glValueId where GLT.ParentRecordId=2 and GLT.ControlName='CONSUMER_ETHNICITY_LIST') tbl5, 

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as Veteran  
FROM dbo.Client C INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=C.glVeteranId where C.Id=2) tbl6, 

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as Religion 
FROM dbo.GeneralLookupTransition GLT INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=GLT.glValueId where GLT.ParentRecordId=2 and GLT.ControlName='CONSUMER_RELIGION_DROPDOWN') tbl7, 

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as Race 
FROM dbo.GeneralLookupTransition GLT INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=GLT.glValueId where GLT.ParentRecordId=2 and GLT.ControlName='CONSUMER_RACE_DROPDOWN') tbl8, 

(SELECT GL.LookupItem as [Language] 
FROM dbo.GeneralLookupTransition GLT INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
GL.Id=GLT.glValueId where GLT.ParentRecordId=2 and GLT.ControlName='CONSUMER_CHARACTERISTIC_LANGUAGE_DROPDOWN') tbl9
```

The result is:

[image]

These some of the columns I got from this query. See the column Ethnicity.
It has 3 different records against a single client. Please tell me how can I convert these three records in a single comma separated records in the same column and these 3 rows become a single row.

Please save the image and then see. May be it is not visible here!

Comment: why not return multiple tables from the query and make relations between them in asp.net?

Comment: No I can't. I just need this Ehtnicity comma-separated. This is the requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is a bit too much for me to process. But here is the answer to the question...

> How to Comma separate multiple rows obtained from a SQL Query

You can use `for xml path('')` like this.

```
declare @T table (GroupID int, Value varchar(10))

insert into @T values (1, 'Row 1')
insert into @T values (1, 'Row 2')
insert into @T values (2, 'Row 3')
insert into @T values (2, 'Row 4')
insert into @T values (2, 'Row 5')

select GroupID,
  stuff(
  (select ','+Value as '*'
   from @T as T2
   where T2.GroupID = T1.GroupID
   for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as [Values]
from @T as T1
group by GroupID
```

Result

```
GroupID     Values
----------- ------------------
1           Row 1,Row 2
2           Row 3,Row 4,Row 5
```

Comment: Good answer; there is a blog post similar to this solution at http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/03/sql-server-combine-multiple-rows-into.html which gives more details on why this work.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an [UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164062.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getEthnicity]
(
    @id Int,
    @delimiter varchar(5)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ethnicity VARCHAR(8000) 
    SELECT   @Ethnicity = COALESCE(@Ethnicity + @delimiter, '') + GLT.DisplayColumn     
    FROM dbo.GeneralLookupTransition GLT INNER JOIN dbo.GeneralLookup GL ON 
        GL.Id=@ID where GLT.ParentRecordId=2 and GLT.ControlName='CONSUMER_ETHNICITY_LIST')
    return @Ethnicity
END
```

This is only an example because i dont know your datamodel.